# Calculate time between one event and the next one in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

| id | user_id | created_at | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2022-12-13 00:12:12 | IN_TRANSIT |
| 2 | 104 | 2022-12-13 01:12:12 | IN_TRANSIT |
| 3 | 100 | 2022-12-13 02:12:12 | DONE |
| 4 | 100 | 2022-12-13 03:12:12 | IN_TRANSIT |
| 5 | 104 | 2022-12-13 04:12:12 | DONE |
| 6 | 100 | 2022-12-13 05:12:12 | DONE |
| 7 | 104 | 2022-12-13 06:12:12 | IN_TRANSIT |
| 7 | 104 | 2022-12-13 07:12:12 | REJECTED |

I am trying to calculate the sum for each user of the idle time, so the time between status DONE and next IN_TRANSIT for that user.

The result should be

| user_id | idle_time |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 01:00:00 |
| 104 | 02:00:00 |

Comment: For a user_id, is it always that 'DONE' status followed by 'IN_TRANSIT' or it may followed by another status?

Comment: @Ahmed, another status can also come, so it's not 100% DONE always after IN_TRANSIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select    user_id
         ,idle_time
from     (
          select  user_id
                 ,status
                 ,created_at-lag(created_at) over(partition by user_id order by created_at)   as idle_time
                 ,lag(status) over(partition by user_id order by created_at)                  as pre_status
          from    t 
         ) t
where    status     = 'IN_TRANSIT'
and      pre_status = 'DONE'
```

| user_id | idle_time |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 01:00:00 |
| 104 | 02:00:00 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kKUEcdS1?hide=2)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select user_id, min(case status when 'IN_TRANSIT' then created_at end) -
       min(case status when 'DONE' then created_at end) idle_time
from
  (
    select user_id, created_at, status,
           sum(case status when 'DONE' then 1 end) over (partition by user_id order by created_at) as grp
    from table_name 
  ) T
group by user_id, grp
having min(case status when 'IN_TRANSIT' then created_at end) -
       min(case status when 'DONE' then created_at end) is not null
```

This will find the time difference between 'DONE' status and the first next 'IN_TRANSIT' status, if there is a multiple 'IN_TRANSIT' statuses after and you want to find the difference with the last one just change `min(case status when 'IN_TRANSIT' then created_at end)` to max.

Also, if there are multiple 'DONE', 'IN_TRANSIT' for a user_id, then they will show as a separate rows in the result, but you can use this query as a subquery to find the sum of all differences grouped by user_id.

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0ZxFg6Kp).

Answer (score -1):

you need to use lag function for finding the diff between first and second row

```
select user_id,idle_time from (select user_id,status,
 created_at - lag(created_at) over (order by user_id, created_at)
  as idle_time
from calctime)
as drt  WHERE  idle_time > interval '10 sec' and status='IN_TRANSIT'
```